# Cumsum while value at another column not change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to calculate the sum of values from one column, where the value at another column not changes

Example:

df.A

```
0   |  A   |  2 
1   |  A   |  1 
2   |  A   |  3 
3   |  B   |  22 
4   |  A   |  0
5   |  B   |  8
```

What I want to have is a new column:

```
                  |  cum.sum
0   |  A   |  2   |    6   (=2+1+3+0)
1   |  A   |  1   |    6
2   |  A   |  3   |    6
3   |  B   |  22  |    31  (=22+8)
4   |  A   |  0   |    6
5   |  B   |  8   |    6
```

Comment: `df.groupby('col1').col3.transform('sum')`

Comment: Your output seems to be incorrect?

Comment: @WeNYoBen Thank you, your approach is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output in your example appears to be a simple `sum` not a `cumsum`, in which case it's:

`df["C"] = df.groupby("A")["B"].transform("sum")`

However if you do want `cumsum` you can just switch the function name:

`df["C"] = df.groupby("A")["B"].transform("cumsum")`

(sum gives the same output for each row of A`s in the DataFrame, whereas cumsum gives the total of A's in the rows up to and including the current row.)

Comment: cumsum no need transform

Comment: Thank you, @Toby Petty, you are right about regular sum instead of cumsum. Your approach is right